# Can I create a public file with AWS SDK for .Net using Amazon.S3.IO.S3FileInfo

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating files in an S3 bucket using AWS SDK for .Net, I'm using S3FileInfo, everything is working fine but the files are created private, and I cannot seem to find a way to create them public.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"By default your Amazon S3 buckets and objects are private. To make an object viewable by using a URL, for example https://s3.amazonaws.com/Bucket/Object, you must make the object publicly readable. Otherwise, you will need to create a signed URL that includes a signature with authentication information."

You can make an object publicly readable by adding an entry to the Access Control List. It can done via `PutACL()` method in `AmazonS3Client` class.

Here's the working example:

```
static void Main()
{
    // data
    const string accessKeyId = "AKIAIR42XOXH7RXDLVTA";
    const string secretAccessKey = "z4cODfNLYU0YGf7MnXMCXGib2QaxM+inbA1UZw3k";
    const string testBucket = "qwe.SampleBucket";
    const string testFile = "testFile.txt";

    using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
    {
        // creating a file
        var s3FileInfo = new S3FileInfo(s3Client, testBucket, testFile);
        using (var streamWriter = s3FileInfo.CreateText())
        {
            streamWriter.Write("TestContent");
        }

        // setting a permission
        s3Client.PutACL(new PutACLRequest
        {
            BucketName = testBucket,
            Key = testFile,
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
        });
    }
}
```